# How to style the underline effect of a static link using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here's what my code looks like: (please run the code snippet below)

```css
.hover-underline-animation {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}

.hover-underline-animation:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #0087ca;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
    color: #243b55;
}

.hover-underline-animation:hover:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    color: #243b55;
}

.active-hover-underline-animation {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #0087ca;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
    color: #0087ca;
}
```

```html
<a class="hover-underline-animation" href="#">Hover me to see the effect</a> <br>

<p>There's a text below me that is now hidden because its CSS isn't working as I intended.</p>

<a class="active-hover-underline-animation" href="#">Why can't I get the same effect even if not hovered when static?</a>
```

Basically, what I want to achieve is to style the second link -- with blue underline and text-color that looks the same as the first link-- without having to hover to see its styling.

There's no need for the animation effect, just the final output (what it looks like after the animation is finished.

I'm going to use this to show to the users this is the current page they're in.

**EDIT:** Why can't I get the same effect as the first link for the second link without having to hover to see its style?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I understood you want to style the second link with a blue underline which is always there (and not just popping on hover) and with no animation am I correct?

Comment: @UmbertoFontanazza Exactly! blue underline which is always there to show it's the current page the user is in.

Comment: Your, question is not clear. Please clear your question and update it.

Comment: But do you want the static underline to look just like the one you get on the other link on hover or do you want it to look like the 'standard' link underline that the browser has in built?

Comment: @A Hamworth Yes, I want it to have the same style as the first one and not the standard link underline. Though since it's static, the animation shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the class styling your second link is this:

```css
.active-hover-underline-animation {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #0087ca;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
    color: #0087ca;
}
```

Beware that I think you should just delete the class since it is meant to be applied to the pseudo element `::after` and not to the anchor tag. The element is not showing because the said class is shrinking the element to 2px with the line `height: 2px;`.

The following line `text-decoration: none;` removes the underline which is present by default on all anchor tags. So you need to remove that line and add a line to change the color of the underline (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)) like the following: `text-decoration-color: #0087ca;`.

If you want a class to style an anchor tag just use the following applying you favourite class name and you can apply it to the anchor element of your choice with the HTML attibute `class="your-class-name"` like in the following:

```css
.your-class-name {
  text-decoration-color: #0087ca;
  text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="your-class-name">I'm an anchor tag</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my post. I will try this and see if I can get what I'm trying to achieve!

Comment: Let me know how it goes

Comment: I didn't know ```text-decoration-color``` and ```text-decoration-thickness``` exist! Those were useful fix. Thanks again for explaining it!

Comment: `text-decoration-thickness` was introduced recently, so check browser support because IE and Firefox for mobile don't support it as you can see in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-thickness#browser_compatibility).
Remember that `text-decoration` property is a shorthand for `text-decoration-line`, `text-decoration-color`, `text-decoration-style` and `text-decoration-thickness` just as `border` is a shorthand for `border-width`, `border-style` and `border-color`.

Comment: You're very helpful and I really appreciate it! Thanks very much!